# Cannot gzip excluded sitemesh pages

Tags: java, servlets, gzip, servlet-filters, sitemesh

In a servelt application, I've added a Gzip filter (/*, REQUEST) and config it be the first in the filter chain. It works fine with Sitemesh's filter (/*, REQUEST, FORWARD) except that when the request is excluded as specified in deocorators.xml (e.g. for ajax request), the gzip filter throws an illegal state.

The gzip filter comes from http://jsp.codefetch.com/example/54/CompressionFilter/src/CompressionResponseWrapper.java

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather configure Gzipping at servletcontainer level. Every self-respected servletcontainer supports it. Since it's unclear which one you're using and Tomcat is the most popular/cloned/forked one, here's a Tomcat targeted example so that you at least have a clue where to look in your servletcontainer.

Open `/conf/server.xml`, locate the [`<Connector>`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) element and add `compression="on"` to it.

```
<Connector (...) compression="on" />
```

That's it.

Comment: We are using jetty, which seems to be using GZipFilter.